# Strings and numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm writing a quite simple Python code using classes and numba and everything was OK until I had the 'brilliant' idea of passing an array of strings to `__init__()`. The first relevant lines of code are shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import float64, types
from numba.experimental import jitclass

spec = [('p_', float64), ('T_', float64), ('pc_', float64), ('Tc_', float64), \
        ('rhoc', float64), ('omega_', float64), ('MW_', float64), \
        ('zf', float64), ('rho', float64), ('visc', float64), \
        ('Comps', types.unicode_type[:]), ('Y', float64[:])]

@jitclass(spec)
class Viscosity:

    def __init__(self, p_, T_, Comps, Y):
        ....
```

**Comps** is what is giving me trouble. Typically, **Comps** would be something like `np.array(['CH4','C2H6'])`. I might have made it simply a list, `['CH4','C2H6']`, instead of an array, but that doesn't matter as it would not work anyway. No numerical or string manipulations are done on those strings anywhere in the code; I just want to have them passed to `__init__()`.

I found a simple example where a string is declared as `types.unicode_type` and tried to adapt it to my slightly more complicated case, but it didn't work.

There should be a way to circumvent this, since no processing is done on the strings. I might as well wipe numba completely out from my code, as execution time is not critical in this little project and probably will never be an issue. But I don't like the idea of giving up easily on things like those.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It starts working correctly when I replaced `[:]` to `types.ListType`.
Take into account that all methods of a jitclass are compiled into nopython functions.

```r
import numpy as np
from numba import float64, f8, types
from numba.experimental import jitclass

spec = [('p_', float64), ('T_', float64), ('pc_', float64), ('Tc_', float64), \
        ('rhoc', float64), ('omega_', float64), ('MW_', float64), \
        ('zf', float64), ('rho', float64), ('visc', float64), \
        ('Comps', types.ListType(types.unicode_type)), ('Y', types.ListType(f8))]

@jitclass(spec)
class Viscosity:

    def __init__(self, p_, T_, Comps, Y):
        return print(Comps)
    
    
Viscosity(2.0, 2.0, ["a", "b"], [1.0, 2.0])
# ['a' 'b']
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply and explanation. Your code works, but at the cost of a large number of warning messages, so large I cannot copy them in here. I will play with your snippet to see what I can learn from it. Perhaps I should've said that I use Python 3.8.5 and numba 0.53.0 on a Xubuntu 20.04-64 machine.

Comment: I think that part (but not all) of my problem has a lot to do with what I want to do with **Comps** after having it passed to ```__init__()```. I want to make a copy of it to another list by using, ```self.Comp = Comps.copy()``` and numba somehow does not like that, whatever the method I use to get that copy made.